# Disable Drobpox Microsoft office integration?

Tags: microsoft-office, dropbox

Dropbox has an integration with Microsoft office Programmes (Word, Excel etc) where it dispalys a dropbox badge in the left hand side of the programme window to allow you to @ and comment on items in the document via Dropbox. Is it possible to disable this ?

Comment: See this...https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams/Disable-DropBox-Integration/td-p/102207

Answer (score 0):

I think [this link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams/Disable-DropBox-Integration/td-p/102207) will help solve your problem.